# Name of an archaic type of RSA padding (0BBBBBBB...)

Tags: rsa, padding

In some legacy code, I encountered RSA signature padding in the following format (hexadecimal):

`0B BB BB BB BB BB BB ... BB BB <hash>`

Is there a name for this simple type of RSA padding?  I would think that the original developers got this design from something.

Comment: This looks vaguely similar to [ANSI X9.31 padding](http://collaboration.cmc.ec.gc.ca/science/rpn/biblio/ddj/Website/articles/DDJ/2001/0105/0105c/0105cf4.htm), except that the first byte in X9.31 padding is `6B` instead of `0B`, and the last one is `BA`.

Comment: Although I don't know the background of the legacy code, I think you could well be assuming too much.